# Update jsonb column with value from row_to_json()

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table containing a data that look like:

```
col1       col2     col3     col4      json_data  
----------------------------------------------------
 a           b        c       d       {"mock":"abc123"}
 e           f        g       h       {"mock":"def456"}
```

The column `json_data` is a column with jsonb type that contains some json that do not relate to anything which I want to update with `row_to_json()` function. The result should be something like this

```
col1       col2     col3     col4      json_data  
----------------------------------------------------
 a           b        c       d       {"col1:"a", "col2:"b","col3:"c","col4:"d"}
 e           f        g       h       {"col1:"e", "col2:"f","col3:"g","col4:"h"}
```

which will get the result from row_to_json function to update each row. I am not sure how can I use the UPDATE query to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function [`to_jsonb()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) and the `-` operator to remove the column `json_data` from the resulting json object:

```
create table my_table(col1 text, col2 text, col3 text, col4 text, json_data jsonb);
insert into my_table values
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '{"mock":"abc123"}'),
('e', 'f', 'g', 'h', '{"mock":"def456"}');

update my_table t
set json_data = to_jsonb(t)- 'json_data'
returning *;

 col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |                      json_data                       
------+------+------+------+------------------------------------------------------
 a    | b    | c    | d    | {"col1": "a", "col2": "b", "col3": "c", "col4": "d"}
 e    | f    | g    | h    | {"col1": "e", "col2": "f", "col3": "g", "col4": "h"}
(2 rows)
```

You can remove more than one column, e.g.:

```
update my_table t
set json_data = to_jsonb(t)- 'json_data'- 'col3'- 'col4'
returning *;

 col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |         json_data          
------+------+------+------+----------------------------
 a    | b    | c    | d    | {"col1": "a", "col2": "b"}
 e    | f    | g    | h    | {"col1": "e", "col2": "f"}
(2 rows)
```

Alternatively, you can use `jsonb_build_object()` instead of `to_jsonb()`:

```
update my_table t
set json_data = jsonb_build_object('col1', col1, 'col2', col2)
returning *;

 col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |         json_data          
------+------+------+------+----------------------------
 a    | b    | c    | d    | {"col1": "a", "col2": "b"}
 e    | f    | g    | h    | {"col1": "e", "col2": "f"}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Sorry for not being specific but if I want just only a specific column to be in the json_data e.g. col1 and col2 in json_data. How can I do that?

Comment: Remove unwanted columns just like `json_data` was removed.

Comment: Can you give some example? I am not really sure about that (currently not at my desk rn)

Comment: Sorry but can this be done with an ordered attribute like col1, col2 ,col3 and so on. I tried both to_jsonb and jsonb_build_object but not worked e.g. it showed as col2, col1, col3. I need it to be in the same order as the column

Comment: I knew that json is an unordered collection of value pairs but can it be fixed?

Comment: You can alter the type of the column to `json` and use appropriate functions `to_json()` or `json_build_object()`. However, I wouldn't do that, you should accept the nature of json.

Comment: Ok, thanks for fast replying. Seem like I have  to play around with my python code instead since this update query produce unordered attribute that might fixed if I have the same update everytime

Comment: Well, in fact, results are repeatable. The keys are ordered from shortest to longest (alphabetically for keys with even length). Though the sort order is not officially documented.

Comment: I don't want to change any type in th table but my idea is to create a temp table that has the same attribute as the real one, then alter the table to json and order the array manually then insert that row to jsonb column in the real table. My concern is that can json value insert to jsonb column?